# Query doesn't work when parameter's are provided

Tags: java, mysql, database

This Works just fine

```
conn = DatabaseConnection.getConnection();
stmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM Persons ORDER by firstName Desc");
rs = stmt.executeQuery();
```

But this one doesn't work

```
conn = DatabaseConnection.getConnection();
stmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM Persons ORDER by ? ?");
stmt.setString(1, "firstName");
stmt.setString(2, "Desc");
rs = stmt.executeQuery();
```

Not sure why this would not work. Both my parameters are variables and that's the reason I would want to set it explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Placeholders (?) in prepared statements are used for column replacement. You cannot set the 'DESC' attribute of `ORDER BY` using `setString` method.

From [PreparedStatement setString javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setString(int,%20java.lang.String)):

> ```
>  * Sets the designated parameter to the given Java <code>String</code> value.
>  * The driver converts this
>  * to an SQL <code>VARCHAR</code> or <code>LONGVARCHAR</code> value
>  * (depending on the argument's
>  * size relative to the driver's limits on <code>VARCHAR</code> values)
>  * when it sends it to the database.
> ```

In case you want to take the ORDER as a parameter to your DAO method then simply use String replacement in the query. Maybe like this:

```
public myDAOMethod(String firstName, String order) {

    String query = "SELECT * FROM Persons ORDER by ? " + order;
    conn = DatabaseConnection.getConnection(query);
    stmt = conn.prepareStatement();
    stmt.setString(1, "firstName");
    rs = stmt.executeQuery();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually your query converted into something like in case of prepared statement:

```
SELECT * FROM Persons ORDER by 'firstname' 'Desc'
```

This behaviour provides protection against SQL injection.